# jQuery .parent() class selector

Tags: jquery, selector, parent

This is my code:

*HTML*

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-frame">
        <div class="popup-cont">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
s.popup = {
    set : function(e){
        if(e)   $.get(s.v+e+'.php', function(e){$('.popup .inner').append(e).parent().parent().parent().show()})
        else    $('.popup .inner').empty().parent().parent().parent().hide();
    }
}
```

Idea is: 
if(e)

1. append $.get response to  `.popup .inner`
2. show  `.popup`

else

1. empty  `.popup .inner`
2. hide  `.popup`

**Question**

Is there better way to select `.popup` than
 `.parent().parent().parent()`

Additional:
Im aware that this could be done like this:

```
$('.popup .inner').empty(); $('.popup').hide();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use closest method to select the closest parent.

Check : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Replace

`$('.popup .inner').empty().parent().parent().parent().hide();`

with

`$('.popup .inner').empty().closest('.popup').hide();`

Comment: Can't you rather do `$('.popup .inner').empty().parent('.popup').hide();` for the safty it provides given that there might exist more popups?

Comment: My bad, that was mootools, not jQuery, closest only goes up the tree.

Comment: @Alxandr: `.parent('.popup')` would match the direct parent with a class `.popup` which is not the case here.